# How can i control qscrollarea horizontally

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have a `QScrollArea` and I want to use scroll function only horizontally. Scrollbar policy is 'AlwaysOff' because I want to hide scrollbar.

I hope to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to the widget to be able to scroll horizontally only, vertically it should be fixed.
For that use

```
void    setSizePolicy ( QSizePolicy )
```

or

```
void    setSizePolicy ( QSizePolicy::Policy horizontal, QSizePolicy::Policy vertical )
```

where you can specify the vertical policy to be fixed and horizontal policy as required by you.

Hope this helps. Please leave a comment if you intended something different and/or above solution does not solve your problem.

Comment: not solved. But I found another solution. When 'Alt' key pressed, wheel event affects qscrollarea hoizontally. It's not so bad. Thank you